# ASN1 and canonical octect encoding rules (COER) in Python

Tags: python, encoding, asn.1

I have some messages data structures represantations in ASN1. These messages have to sent using the canonical octect encoding rule (COER). I currently user asn1c for python,but, there is no support for coer. How could I create the instances and later do the encoding in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you might be in trouble. COER looks like it was standardised relatively recently (bearing in mind that ASN.1 is well over 30 years old), and I don't think that a lot of the tools have caught up yet.

The tools from OSS Nokalva seem to support COER, but they don't do a Python binding, and their tools are quite pricey (but very good).

For Python the "goto" has been the pyasn1 library, which doesn't seem to do COER (or even PER, which is a real pity).

Objective Systems, which are also very good, now do a [Python ASN.1 compiler](https://www.obj-sys.com/docs/acv74/acv74PythonUsersGuide.pdf)(which trumps pyasn1's code first approach), but that doesn't yet do COER.

The easiest thing might be whince, fork out for the OSS Nokalva tools, and use Iron Python to interop with their C# library and tools. That might seem an expensive way of doing it, but if your project is on a fixed timescale, that might be the lowest risk way of accomplishing what you want. You'd likely not be having to write any code to "do" COER, and instead you can concentrate on the application itself and avoid writing your own COER implementation that'd be a pain to maintain, and will eventually get surpassed by other ASN.1 tools anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying expensive way?

Comment: @NikosIliakis I mean that a software tool that costs some money can end up saving a project a lot of time, and therefore a lot of money even if the tool's price is expensive. If a project has limited manpower, but has the budget to buy the tools, then that limited manpower is used more effectively doing other parts of the project. It's not the "open source" way, where everything has to be free, but if your project is not open source then buying a commercial tool is a possible way forward.